# Python copying certain lines from one file to another

Tags: python, file-io

I want to copy specific lines from one file to another.

I can copy the entire file quite easily with:

```
or_profile_file = open('or_profile.prof')
new_profile_file = open('new_profile.prof','w')

for line in or_profile_file:
    new_profile_file.write(line)

or_profile_file.close()
new_profile_file.close()
```

How can I copy only specific lines though? In this case I want to copy only the first 109 lines, but would also be interested in knowing how to copy different specific lines, for instance copying lines 1,5,38 and 200?

Comment: C'mon, guys, give the OP some slack - he is probably a scientist trying to grok some data, not a professional programmer.

Comment: Thank you (-: But who gave me any trouble?

Comment: Your question was downvoted and someone casted a "close" vote. Welcome to stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: Oo OK. Well I understand the frustration of the experienced/professional programmers. I am indeed a 'scientist trying to grok some data'. I really like SO but wish there was a Stack Exchange aimed more at the programming side of scientific computing. It would make people like me allot less scared of asking basic questions such as this.

Comment: Don't worry about asking newbie questions. After sometime you will start to realize the answer halfway posting the question (this is one of the goals of stackoverflow: [rubberduck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)). The system works most of the time, you need 5 close votes in order to close a question because it is not uncommon to have an overzealous moderator casting a debatable close vote to a perfectly good question.

Comment: Interesting article. I can certainly admit to this having happened to me quite a few times. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumerate to get the line number while iterating over the file:

```
desired_lines = [1, 5, 38, 200]

for n, line in enumerate(or_profile_file):
    if (n+1) in desired_lines:
        new_profile_file.write(line)
```

Note that n starts at zero, I assume you are counting from 1, that is why I test for (n+1).

Comment: Thank you Paulo. And if I want to copy lines 1 to 196? I tried desired_lines = [1:196], but get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Just change the `if` test to `if n < 196` instead, and so on.

Comment: I redefined desired_lines as an array: desired_lines = np.arange(1,197) and this did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: in native python there is a function called `range` that is commonly used for this, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate to find out line numbers and write them accordingly:

```
or_profile_file = open('or_profile.prof')
new_profile_file = open('new_profile.prof','w')

lines_to_write = [1, 5, 38, 200]

for linenum, line in enumerate(or_profile_file):
    if linenum+1 in lines_to_write:
        new_profile_file.write(line)

or_profile_file.close()
new_profile_file.close()
```

Do note that line numbers start from 0. That's why it's `linenum+1`